# accessing CSS static resource in Lighting Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

How do you access (referencing) CSS static resource file in Lightning Web Component (LwC) html?   I have included the css under the "staticresources" folder and its uploaded in the salesforce static resource section.

I am referring this help doc but don't see how to reference css - 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_resources

Answer (score 11):

You will most likely need to utilize `loadStyle(self, fileUrl): Promise`
 from `lightning/platformResourceLoader`. You can find a sample on [Use Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library)

> The `platformResourceLoader` module has two methods,  `loadScript` and `loadStyle`. Both methods return promises, which can be chained or used in parallel. You control the load sequence of your scripts or styles.

```
import resourceName from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/resourceName';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

loadStyle(this, resourceName + '/yourstyle.css')
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue. The Salesforce docs show how to reference numerous resources except css, lol. There are a few details worth pointing out that the Salesforce doc doesn't explicitly mention:

I'll assume you are writing this in VSCode and have the default file structure (e.g. force-app\main\default etc.). Let's pretend you have your desired css in a file called `myStaticStyles.css`. Add `myStaticStyles.css` to your `staticresources` folder. Then, create a new file called `myStaticStyles.resource-meta.xml` file.

And here is what the code will look like:

*controller.js*

```
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import myStaticStyles from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myStaticStyles'
/* notice that it's just myStaticStyles, not myStaticStyles.css.
The LWC framework will automatically compile your .css and .resource-meta.xml files
into the necessary css resource. 
*/
export default class Controller extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        loadStyle(this, myStaticStyles); 
        //you can add a .then().catch() if you'd like, as loadStyle() returns a promise
    }
}
```

*myStaticStyles.resource-meta.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <contentType>text/css</contentType>
</StaticResource>
```

There are other tags you can add to configure your settings, but this is all you need to get things working. A `.resource-meta.xml` file is necessary in order to successfully deploy from source to org.

And your *myStaticStyles.css* will just have normal css.

Make sure you `SFDX: Deploy source to org` the static resources folder. Sometimes I would only deploy my component code and not realize the static resources were left behind.